# Reference request: identifying cohomology with dual of toral subalgebra

Tags: representation-theory

I am trying to understand David Speyer's answer in this post:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31639/getting-the-weyl-dimension-formula-geometrically,

where he mentions that, for a compact semisimple Lie group $G$ with maximal torus $T$, there is an identification $H^2(G/T)$ with $\mathfrak{t}^*$. Does someone know of an easy account (in the sense of being easier than Hirzebruch's paper on Characteristic Classes of Homogeneous Spaces) of how this identification is made?

Many thanks.